# Getting "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when running chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I run this code:

```py
browser = webdriver.chrome('/Users/hamudsadek/Downloads/chromedriver')
```

I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you post the rest of your code, or a reproducible example of your code, it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

That's because you called `selenium.webdriver.chrome` as a class but you should have it `selenium.webdriver.Chrome`. Fix the typo on the capital "C" will make it work.